# how get record from db before given date in JPA

Tags: java

```
public List<Trans> findByDate(Date date1) {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT k FROM Trans WHERE k.transDate= :transDate ORDER BY k.transDate")
            .setParameter("transDate", date1);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

that is part of my code in jpa, how if i want to check if there are records in 'Trans' table with transDate before date1?
thank you

Comment: did you try by reading documentation or tutorials?

Comment: yes, but i'm bad at googling because i'm bad at english, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the '<' operator

```
public List<Trans> findByDate(Date date1) {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT k FROM Trans WHERE k.transDate < :transDate ORDER BY k.transDate")
            .setParameter("transDate", date1);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```